# How to exclude the import of schemas in WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl, weblogic-10.x

I want to remove the import of schema in the WSDL instead want the schema elements to be present in the WSDL.

Im using Weblogic 10.3 Web Servics JAXWS where as i have tried this

```
<jwsc srcdir="src" destdir="${ear-dir}" keepgenerated="false" defaultexcludes="false"           
        classpathref="lib.path">

        <jws file="credit/sfa/ws/CreditCheckService.java" type="JAXWS">

            <WLHttpTransport contextPath="cdtibws" serviceUri="CreditCheckService" portName="CreditCheckServicePort" />
        </jws>

    </jwsc>
```

with the annotated services class

```
@WebService(serviceName = "CreditCheckService", name = "CreditCheckServicePortType", targetNamespace = "http://www.xxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
//@WLHttpTransport(contextPath = "/xxxxx", serviceUri = "xxxx", portName = "ComplexServicePort")


public class CreditCheckService {

    /**
     *
     * @param SfaRequest
     * @return SfaResponse
     */

@WebMethod(operationName = "processRequest")

@WebResult(name = "CreditCheckResponse",partName="CreditCheckResponse",targetNamespace = "http://www.xxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
    public CreditCheckResponse processRequest(@WebParam(name="CreditCheckRequest",targetNamespace="http://www.xxxxx.com/webservices/CDT")credit.sfa.beans.CreditCheckRequest creditCheckRequest) {

            credit.sfa.beans.CreditCheckResponse creditCheckResponse = null;
            SFAService service = new SFAService();
            creditCheckResponse = service.processCreditCheck(creditCheckRequest);
          service.processCreditCheck()");
            return creditCheckResponse ;
    }
```

annotated beans class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CreditCheckResponse", namespace = "http://www.xxxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
@XmlType(name = "CreditCheckRequest", namespace = "http://www.xxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)

public class CreditCheckResponse implements Serializable {
@XmlElement(name = "MsgResponseCd", namespace = "http://www.xxxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
private Integer MsgResponseCd;
@XmlElement(name = "MsgResponseDesc", namespace = "http://www.xxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
private String MsgResponseDesc;
@XmlElement(name = "CreditBalanceAmt", namespace = "http://www.xxxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
private long CreditBalanceAmt;
_____________________________________________________________


@XmlRootElement(name = "CreditCheckRequest", namespace = "http://www.xxxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
@XmlType(name = "CreditCheckRequest", namespace = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/webservices/CDT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class CreditCheckRequest implements Serializable {
@XmlElement(name = "SrcSystem", namespace = "http://www.xxxxx.com/webservices/CDT" )

private String SrcSystem = null;
@XmlElement(name = "UserId", namespace = "http://www.xxxxx.com/webservices/CDT" )
private String UserId;
@XmlElement(name = "RequestCd", namespace = "http://www.xxxxx.com/webservices/CDT" )
private int RequestCd;
@XmlElement(name = "RequestCdDesc", namespace = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/webservices/CDT" )
private String RequestCdDesc;
@XmlElement(name = "SalesAgentId", namespace = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/webservices/CDT" )
private int SalesAgentId = 0;
```

CAN ANY ONE SUGGEST what attributes or annotation to be used to elumintae the import of schema from the WSDL file.

Thanks in advance!